# Anychart cookie problem, SameSite attribute

Tags: javascript, html, charts, anychart, tag-cloud

I added a tagCloud chart from Anychart in my landing page but I find this warning and chart isn't visible since few days.

This is the warning I get
[image: SameSite attribute warning]

This is the script

```js
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-tag-cloud.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

**Update**

I configured the chart like this

```js
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

      var data = [
        {"x": "Family", "value": 10, category: "Family"},
        {"x": "Friends", "value": 10, category: "Friends"}
      ];

      var chart = anychart.tagCloud(data);
      var tooltip = chart.tooltip();
      chart.tooltip().useHtml(true);
      tooltip.positionMode("point");
      tooltip.format("Goal steps: <b>{%value}");

      chart.tooltip(false);

      chart.angles([0])

      chart.container("wordCloudChart");

      var dict = {
        "Family": "https://www.google.com",
        "Friends": "https://www.google.it"
      };

      chart.listen("pointClick", function(e){
        for(var key in dict) {
        var valueSelected = dict[e.point.get("x")];
        window.open(valueSelected, "_blank");
        }
      });

      chart.background().fill({
      keys: ["#2a2a2a", "#2a2a2a", "#2a2a2a"],
      angle: 130,
      });

      chart.tooltip().format(function(e){
      var value = ((this.value)*100)/200000;
      return "Value: " + value + "%";
      });

      chart.scale(anychart.scales.linear());

      chart.draw();
    });
```

Comment: We will update our site to provide correct cookies according to this security update. but these warnings should not block access to AnyChart binaries. There's something else. Do you receive any other errors or warnings? Can you provide your chart configuration code?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I edited my question with the code of the graph but from the console of my browser the only warning I see is about SameSite and cookie.

Comment: Thanks! Your code is absolutely ok. Please, try to download the AnyChart binaries from our CDN and run the chart with downloaded binaries and let us know about the result. Probably your browser refuses CDN requests. As we know, in the future these warnings will refuse requests, but it not in the current version of Chrome.

Comment: @AnyChartSupport can you provide me a link please? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, all binaries are available on the CDN page - https://www.anychart.com/download/cdn/

Answer (score 0):

After recreation of your particular situation, there was no problem as you've described. Let us know if the issue persists.

We hope that this issue did not affect your website's accessibility or performance. Also, we did notify our development team about this possible problem.